# How do I disable html closing tag completion?

Tags: phpstorm, jetbrains-ide

In phpstorm whenever I type `</` it automatically closes what it thinks is the appropriate tag to close but I'd like to turn this off, but I cannot find the setting to do this. Does anyone know what setting this is?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Settings | Editor | Smart Keys | Automatically insert closing tag`

**P.S.**
Settings screen has very handy search box which will narrow possible settings **a lot**.

Comment: I tried turning that off but it doesn't help. Tags will still close as soon as I type in the </

Comment: Well ... what can I say -- I was expecting that to work (used to be the case in the past). **1)** People have asked for this specific behaviour: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112914 **2)** Seems like there is no option to turn off this behaviour for those who do not like this kind of auto completion: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119253 -- please vote/comment and maybe they will add it (unless some hidden option is available .. but I have found none when searching using standard keywords)

Comment: Perhaps it's a bug then. Thanks for the help though and for pointing me towards the issue on their tracker.