# PHPStorm IDE auto-completion

Tags: php, html, ide, phpstorm

I am using PHPStorm to do some editing of PHP/HTML files and I've noticed whenever I open a tag, if I type `</` it automatically closes the tab. How do I disable this? It's not a behaviour I'm used to and it's becoming a pain to use.

Note: I've disabled all auto-completion options I can find.

Comment: See my comment in http://stackoverflow.com/a/22486622/783119

Comment: thanks. Could you post your final verdict as an answer so that I can accept it here?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I disable html closing tag completion?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22486549/how-do-i-disable-html-closing-tag-completion)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

People have asked to have such specific behaviour (very handy -- I'm loving it, works perfectly): http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-112914

Seems like there is no option to turn off this behaviour for those who do not like this kind of auto completion: http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-119253 -- please vote/comment and maybe they will add it.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Guess I'll have to wait until they update then :/